# MS IE relative path syntax in CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, relative-path

I am using the following CSS code:

```
body
{
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='//images/homebg.png', sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='//images/homebg.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
  background-image: url('../images/homebg.png');
}
```

As you can see I want to cover a background image in MS IE on this page. This CSS code sits in a /`styles/` directory whereas the image is in the `/images/` directory

How do I declare a relative path to the background image from within this CSS code?

Also, am I doing this the right way- i.e. apply the AlphaImageLoader filter to achieve the CSS `background-size: cover;` effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried entering

```
../images/homebg.png
```

As for the filter itself, it looks okay to me.

Comment: Except...in Chrome the image stretches gracefully (both x & y) for bigger screen resolutions, while in IE width covers x but not y. A screenshot at [link](http://img291.imageshack.us/i/screenshotnostretchbg.jpg/)[/link]. The white on top and bottom shouldn't appear. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how the rest of your CSS looks, but have you made sure that the element receiving this filter has its height set to 100%? IE is VERY bad about dealing with heights automatically, so you usually have to set them. Maybe try setting body to have height: 100% (you might have to play around with min-height too depending on what version of IE you're using).

Comment: Neither setting `height: 100%;` nor `min-height: 100%;` work! 
I am attaching this to the `body`- the entire CSS for which is in the next comment

Comment: `body
{ 
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 11pt;
 background-color: #153460;
 margin: 0.5%;
 background-image: url(  '../images/bg.png' );`

Comment: `/*<msie>*/
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/bg.png', sizingMethod='scale');
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/bg.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
 /*</msie>*/
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}`

Comment: Hmmm, I would remove background-position: center. If removing that alone doesn't work, remove background-attachment: fixed and background-repeat: no repeat. You shouldn't need those anyway since you're setting this filter to scale to the bodys width.

Comment: That didn't work but I think I figured out what the problem might be. The stretching maintains aspect ratio...and since the image is rectangular it stretches rectangularly. Will have to check later to confirm though...but that what I think for now!
Thanks though